# How to modify an existing podfile for the latest Xcode version?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to format this pod file for the latest version of Xcode? Build errors with Afnetworking occur only after adding the below code to an existing application's pod file and running the pod install command from the terminal.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'PushChatStarter' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Cards'
end
```

This is the original pod file of the application when everything with Afnetworking works.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0'
```

Afnetworking is operating before the new gems are installed correctly. What is causing Afnetworking to fail at runtime after the pod file update ?

Comment: Either delete `use_frameworks!` from the podfile, or in the code add `import` for each framework you use.

Comment: Can I encourage you to show what the error is? It might help in debugging this issue.

Comment: Please add the exact error message. If you don't want to update AFNetworking while adding new frameworks, use "pod install --no-repo-update"